# Connection between objects in two Python files

Tags: python

How can I share a value of an object between 2 .py files? For example I state the object score in both files, so I will create 2 object I guess even if I import one file to the other one. Is it possible to connect these objects,so if the value will raise on one file, the same value will raise to the other file at the same time? As a result when I raise the value of one object the other file would print the correct value

Comment: what you want is widely considered bad practice and poor style, if it's what it seems like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this variable in a single file only:

```
# file1.py
variable = 6
```

And use it from other files:

```
# file2.py
import file1
file1.variable = 37

# file3.py
import file1
file1.variable = 42
```

Warning: Such sharing of variables is not considered a good practice. Manipulations with such variables should be made using dedicated functions.